# SUMO: How to implement ACO routing algorithm

Tags: routes, shortest-path, sumo

Sumo has Dijkstra.h code in the router directory. Any help to implement Ant colony routing algorithm to find shortest path from source to destination?

Answer (score 0):

If runtime performance is not critical I would not start from the C++ code but with the much shorter and easily understandable python implementation in [https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/master/tools/sumolib/net/**init**.py#L482](https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/master/tools/sumolib/net/__init__.py#L482). To get going, you can safely skip all the stuff about internal edges and have a routing algorithm working on a sumo network in about 25 lines of code. It always gives you a list of edges as return which you can either feed into a route file or use dynamically with TraCI. Then replace it with your own algorithm.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Does that mean that I need to replace existing shortest path code with the ant colony code ?  If yes than,How to use it in Traci?

Comment: No, not replacing, just add another method. You would then call your new method from your TraCI python script, extract all the edge ids and use the vehicle's setRoute method.

Comment: Thanks Michael, Any idea or reference code on implementation of ACO in init.py?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.